# "require is not defined" when I import something from node_modules

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am building a simple Blog App in React, I am newbie React and I am using Routing, so I have to import `Route` from `react-router-dom`, But when I import it like

```
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";
```

then it is showing

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

it happens in every file, I try to import in App.js.

I created a new folder named `js` in `public` folder where the `App.js` is located.

I have tried hours upon hours, But it is still showing that Error.
I have also tried using `browsify` and `webpack` but still showing.

App.js

```
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";

function App() => {
    return (
        <div>
           React App
        </div>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('content')
)
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-react-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.3",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.26.0",
    "history": "^5.3.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^5.70.0"
  }
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>React-App</title>

    <script src="vendor/babel-standalone.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/react.js"></script>
    
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/react-dom.js"></script>
    
  </head>
  
  <script src="https://npmcdn.com/babel-core@5.8.38/browser.min.js"></script>
  <body >
    <div id="content"></div>

    <script
      type="text/babel"
      data-plugins="transform-class-properties"
      src="App.js"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any help would be much Appreciated. Thank You in Advance.

Comment: Show us your `package.json`

Comment: @CristianTraìna, Updated the Question

Comment: Browsers don't support Node module resolution. Using webpack is the way to go, but you need to show us your webpack configuration

Comment: @Quentin, Can you please tell me where the webpack configuration is located ?

Comment: With that as your *index.html* you aren't using Webpack. You should find a better tutorial - client-side Babel is a real pain to deal with. https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#setup-option-2-local-development-environment

Answer (score 0):

I think your `App.js` should be in `src` folder and not in `public`. Try to move it and retry.

Comment: It was in `src` folder but the tutorial I was learning was moved it, and something was not working in that, that's why i moved it.